# Multiple responses from a REST call when expecting one

Tags: websocket, tomcat8, spring-websocket, sockjs, java-websocket

In our project we have implemented spring websockets(4.1.7) functionality but using xhr streaming. UI is developed in angular-JS. From the time we implemented the websockets, we observed lot of exceptions in catalina.out.

We are using sockJS protocol for achieving streaming using spring websocket implementation.

> 2016-04-19 22:14:53,426 [http-bio-8443-exec-17] **ERROR - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public com.xxxxxxx.iop.common.exception.ErrorResponse com.xxxxxxx.iop.common.exception.ExceptionMapper.handleOtherExceptions(java.lang.Exception)**
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:353) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1042) ~[jackson-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2242) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:?]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at com.xxxxxxx.iop.common.filter.CloudCORSFilter.doFilter(CloudCORSFilter.java:87) [iop-common-0.1.jar:0.1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_45]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.23]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:864) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:835) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:170) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalOutputBuffer.java:198) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:305) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:179) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:349) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:510) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:318) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.23]
>       at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
>       at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.flush(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:90) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractHttpSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(AbstractHttpSockJsSession.java:345) ~[?:?]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:325) ~[?:?]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendHeartbeat(AbstractSockJsSession.java:249) ~[?:?]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession$1.run(AbstractSockJsSession.java:269) ~[?:?]
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
>       ... 1 more

---

The real issue here is since this exception is not caught it goes to catalina.out. This is still fine since its more of noise than anything else. but now we realized that some tests fails intermittently due to this issue.

The service that is implementing the websocket is running in the same tomcat with other services. When authenticate call to security service is successful, the response object has two responses one from authentication and other from this exception.

I still dont understand why the error response from the exception is being appended to the successful authenticate call? Why its appending to any random request?

In Spring documentation found following statement which means servlet can write the response to any other thread. But I would like to avoid this and somehow catch the exception and log it
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-fallback

> 25.3.5 Servlet 3 Async Requests HTTP streaming and HTTP long polling SockJS transports require a connection to remain open longer than
>   usual. For an overview of these techniques see this blog post.
>
> In Servlet containers this is done through Servlet 3 async support
>   that allows exiting the Servlet container thread processing a request
>   and continuing to write to the response from another thread.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having same issue. Did You find any solution?

Comment: Only change I did was catch the broken pipe exception and just log it in ExceptionHandler(which has other problem) . I have not seen that issue after that change and may be because we moved to the next spring release (4.2). So answer is really don't know if we have fixed it but at the same we dont see that issue so often.